# Apache TLS (SSL) Performance

Tags: ssl, performance, apache-2.4, https, tls

We are running a fairly powerful dedicated server with a Xeon CPU, 32GB RAM, and RAID SSDs running Centos 6. Yet, we are still seeing HTTPS add over 100ms to our page download time. Is there anything we can do to even get a 20ms speed up?

Here are Apache settings:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-EC$
SSLProxyCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECD$

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/var/run/ssl_scache(5120000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLUseStapling On

SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:/var/run/ssl_stapling(128000)"
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off

SSLStaplingStandardCacheTimeout 3600
SSLStaplingErrorCacheTimeout 600
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
```

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS does slow your website down despite all claims to the contrary. This is because the client and server need to negotiate the SSL/TLS ciphers before it can start. However **after** that, the slowdown is negligible for most sites, and there are massive benefits to SSL.

Additionally the default is http, so someone entering that for a https-only site will need redirecting to the https version leading to another round trip.

100ms is actually not that bad a slowdown for initial connection and, as I say, after that the connection will be established and so there will be no slowdown. So first up, although initial connection speed is important, browsing around a site is also very important and here you shouldn't be affected by the 100ms slowdown.

Your SSL/TLS config actually looks pretty good, both in terms of security and performance. You are using modern and speedy ciphers and suites (though your cipher suite is very restrictive to new browsers only and if that's intentional then you might as well turn off TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 as well), have SSL Caching set up (to save clients renegotiating an SSL session for each connection), and SSL Stapling set up (to save the client an extra lookup to check the validity of your cert).

However some things I can suggest are below. These may reduce impact of using https but will not reduce that initial 100ms connection delay:

1. Ensure Keep-Alives are turned on for the server (should be by default but best to double check). You should ensure you do **not** see a "Connection: close" header in the response. Without Keep-Alives your SSLCache is pointless.
2. Increase your SSLSessionCacheTimeout from 300 seconds or 5 minutes. If on your site and browsing around you could easily go outside that. You've already limited the size of your SSLSessionCache so no harm in increasing this timeout to something higher.
3. Implement HSTS to tell the browser your site always prefers https (even if the user enters no protocol in their browser address bar - or even if they enter http). This will save the initial redirect.
4. HTTP/2 will help with https connection speed as you no loner use parallel connections for that but, more importantly, will help performance in other ways. It is still experimental for Apache though (though seems stable enough to me).

I would also advise you regularly run your server through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html to test your SSL/TLS config as things constantly change in this space as new vulnerabilities are found.

Comment: I know this [page covering time-to-first-byte over TLS](https://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/) is more `nginx`-specific than Apache-specific, but its remarks regarding the size of the certificates and TLS False Start are worth considering.

Comment: Ah now we're getting into the proper hard core stuff. Ilya posts are always insightful and his High-Performance Browser Networking book is well worth a read if you want to delve into it that much. But for the lay person it basically boils down to: run the latest versions :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could enable HTTP/2, which will reduce the number of connections for compatible browsers, reducing page load time. This won't reduce latency for that connection though. Demo [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/http2/).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance) - latency is key in this situation. I ran a speed test against my https server in Sydney, Australia. Testing from another Sydney server the SSL handshake is 46ms, from EC2 in the USA it's 213ms. The difference is because of the round trip packet time, plus there's some unavoidable overhead even if the latency is zero. I don't know what this mandatory latency is, but you could probably work it out by experimentation.

Did you do your testing from a client close to your server, or far away - what's the ping? [Another useful page](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/ssl-latency.html) around https handshake. 100ms probably isn't so bad as an overhead for https.

There could be Apache tweaks someone can recommend. If you post your website link someone could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is not much of an answer but if you are willing to learn how SSL works before optimizing it, here is a **checklist for fast HTTPS**:

- ECDSA certificate
- Entropy source
- TLS1.2 Protocol
- Hardware supported ciphersuites: AES-NI
- SSL session cache
- OCSP stapling
- HTTP/2

All my server-related knowledge is published in this repository https://github.com/szepeviktor/debian-server-tools

All the best!